# ContactsContract API - fetch display name and organization title

Tags: android, api, contacts

How can we fetch displayname and organization.data through ContactsContract APIs using impicit joins so that I can both these values in a single cursor?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code to get the organization name and display name:

```
Cursor organizationNameCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,new String[] {Organization.TITLE,Organization.DISPLAY_NAME}, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId + " AND ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE = '"
                + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                + "'",null,null);

        organizationNameCursor.moveToNext();

        organizationName.setText(organizationNameCursor.getString(organizationNameCursor.getColumnIndex(Organization.TITLE))+" "+organizationNameCursor.getString(organizationNameCursor.getColumnIndex(Organization.DISPLAY_NAME)));
```

Comment: How did you get the contact id?

Answer (score 0):

The ContactsContact data can only be fetched by using content providers which does not allow us to have explicit joins in the query.

You can however have both the values using a single query on Data database as follows:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,new String[] {StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,Organization.COMPANY}, Data..CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId,null,null)
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to retrieve contact id, contact name and organization name for all contacts. If organization is blank, blank string should be returned. From the query above, since you haven't specified the MimeType, the results are not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you wont be able to get the values directly.
You can very well fetch all the details using a single query by adding a parameter

```
Data.MIMETYPE IN (StructuredName,CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
```

however you need to have that logic in your code which would reorder your data.
Each MIMETYPE will fetch a separate record.

Similarly you can use RawContactsEntity for the same. It provides a join between Contacts and Data database internally.